# Is there any way to make couchbase server index a document on insert?

Tags: couchbase

I can use StaleState=false to force a reindex of the documents when querying but this will index all new documents in the bucket.

What I have is a scenario where largely, there is no need to immediately index most documents being inserted (50-100/sec), but a select few (and i do mean few, like once or twice every minute or so) need to be immediately indexed.

StaleState will force the reindex of all documents and i'd rather just reindex the one document and leave the rest to the background indexer.

Is this possible?

Comment: Couchbase is working on something for this; would love to have more specific info about your use case.  Contact me/us if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, there is not.  There is a feature being worked on that will allow an application to be more granular about what updates need to be considered in the query.  It should reduce the cost and thus the latency for queries along these lines.  It may not align perfectly since index recalculation will be in order, but it would be closer.